# Why is it still showing @localhost on liver server

Tags: mysql, laravel

I've been trying to login to my website which I launched recently but I've been getting this error.

SQLSTATE[42000] [1044]Access denied for user 'floatin2_float'@'localhost' to database 'floatin2_float'

in Connection.php (line 647)

I'm wondering why is it still saying localhost in the error even though its been launched onto a live server?

I did the required updates in the .env file.

I've been stuck with this issue for a long time and I absolutely have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: If it’s connecting to the server on the server it is localhost. What should it be? What changes did you make? It’s hard to say without any information

Comment: The changes I made to my .env file is to the database name,username and password to match the credentials of my database on the server and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

When you have pushed the code to server, php, apache and mysql are installed in that server, so when you try to access the database, this database act as local to the server system. Hence it is saying localhost.

Also there the error says, access denied for the user, try to access the server database using that user directly without code. If it works check for typos.

can try to access by changing to another user?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'floatin2_float'@'localhost' to database 'floatin2_float' (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = bharathdundi@gmail.com limit 1)

Comment: try to access db directly by using that user. Also is floatin2_float the name of user as well as name of database?

Comment: Yes floatin2_float is the name of the database and the username

Comment: can try to access by changing to another user?

Comment: Oh my god I just fixed it!!! :).I forgot to add the database to the user and hence why I've been getting this error.